# VBA powerpoint - code to change table's cell shading

Tags: vba, format, cell, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint 2010 presentation with a table on one slide.
I want to create a VBA modeless form that will work like a pallete of
   formats/colors for formatting cells of that table.
Basically, the buttons on the form would just simulate clicking
   specific Shading color in Table Tools/Design menu.

**example:**

I place the cursor to the cell then click on a button in activated modeless form. The shading of that cell will change according to the color in the code.

The reason I want to do this is that some other people will use it and the colors must be easily accessible (format painter doesn't not seem to copy the shading)

But I cannot find a way to make this VBA. I have tried recording macro in Word (not possible in PP) with no success.

Comment: marco recording is not available in powerpoint, i tried it in Word, but the code does not work in powerpoint. Recording in excel also gives a code that is not usable for powerpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Try this... (Not polished code, but should give you what you need(ed))

```
    Public sub TblCellColorFill()

    Dim X As Integer
    Dim Y As Integer
    Dim oTbl as Table

    set oTbl = ActiveWindow.Selection.Shaperange(1).Table   'Only works is a single table shape is selected - add some checks in your final code!

        For X = 1 To otbl.Columns.Count

            For Y = 1 To otbl.Rows.Count

                With otbl.Cell(Y, X)

                    If .Selected <> False Then  'Strange bug - will ignore if statement entirely if you use "= True"
                        'Debug.Print "Test worked " & Now

                      'We have the shape we need
                        .shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 150, 200) 'Add your color here

                    End If
                End With
            Next    'y
        Next    'x
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For table styling in MSPowerPoint 2013 I use

```
Sub STYLE_TABLE_2()
' Change table style 
'  Two rows Dark Gray and White Font 
'  Next odd rows Light Gray/ even Moderate Gray/ and Black Font 

Dim iCols As Integer
Dim iRows As Integer
Dim oTbl As Table

' Debug.Print (ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Type)

With ActiveWindow.Selection
If .Type = ppSelectionShapes Then         ' Shape is selected ppSelectionShapes=2 ppSelectionSlides=3 ppSelectionNone=0

If .ShapeRange(1).Type = msoTable Then    ' If first shape Type=19 is msoTable 
' (--- note not all table-looking shapes are Table style Can be Type=14 msoPlaceholder
   Debug.Print ("We are certain inside table") '
   Set oTbl = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Table   'Only works if single table or its part is selected
      For iCols = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count
         For iRows = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
            With oTbl.Cell(iRows, iCols)
                  .Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
                  .Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 12        
                  If iRows Mod 2 <> 0 Then ' Odd numbers
                Debug.Print ("Ymod2 2") '
                    .Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(236, 234, 241) 
                Else
                    .Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(215, 210, 225) 
                End If
                If (.Selected <> False) And (iRows < 3) Then  'Cannot be "= True"
                    .Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(166, 166, 166)
                    .Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
                    .Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    .Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
                End If
            End With
        Next    'iRows
    Next    'iCols
   End If
  End If
End With
End Sub
```